# What does "${x%% *}" mean in sh?

Tags: shell, shell-script, variable

I just saw "$${x%% *}" in a makefile, which means "${x%% *}" in sh.
Why it is written in this way ?

[how can a makefile detect whether a command is available in the local machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28994/how-can-a-makefile-detect-whether-a-command-is-available-in-the-local-machine)

```
determine_sum = \
        sum=; \
        for x in sha1sum sha1 shasum 'openssl dgst -sha1'; do \
          if type "$${x%% *}" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then sum=$$x; break; fi; \
        done; \
        if [ -z "$$sum" ]; then echo 1>&2 "Unable to find a SHA1 utility"; exit 2; fi

checksums.dat: FORCE
    $(determine_sum); \
    $$sum *.org
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a POSIX shell variable substitution feature :

```
${var%Pattern} Remove from $var the shortest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var.
${var%%Pattern} Remove from $var the longest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var.
```

So if `var="abc def ghi jkl"`

```
echo "${var% *}" # will echo "abc def ghi"
echo "${var%% *}" # will echo "abc"
```

Comment: Not just `bash`, specified by POSIX `sh`. See [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) in Shell Command Language.